# IE insertBefore bug causes tr element cells to be removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I came across an issue that was only reproducable in the latest IE 11 version (11.0.9600.1828CO) and was wondering if there is something I am doing wrong or if this is a bug to file against the browser.

What I am trying to achieve is to rearrange existing td/th elements in their respective rows by swapping them using pure JavaScript on HTML elements. The catch seems to be that when I make the first row absolutely positioned in order to achieve a fixed header row, the tr element's cells property is not updated correctly.

```
<tr id="headerRow" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"><th>Column 0</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>Column 5</th></tr>
```

The algorithm is simple:

> Source Element: largest row index being swapped (ex. 4)
>
> Target Element: smallest row index of the two being swapped (ex. 3)
>
> 1) Record the next sibling element with the largest row index (referred to as the sourceElement) for reference later, if it exists (may not if at the end of the row)
>
> 2) If the target element has a sibling, place the source element before it using insertBefore, otherwise appendChild for the row since the target must be the last cell
>
> 3) Then if the sibling was found in step one, place the target element before it using insertBefore, otherwise appendChild for the same reason
>
> 4) Repeat this for every row in the table

Here is the JS Fiddle:

```js
window.clickFunction = function(currentIndex, newIndex) {
 window.swapColumns(currentIndex,5);
  window.swapColumns(newIndex,5);
  window.swapColumns(currentIndex,5);
};

window.swapColumns = function(currentIndex, newIndex) {
 // Swap so that the largest index is always inserted before the other
 if (currentIndex < newIndex)
 {
  var tempIndex = newIndex;
  newIndex = currentIndex;
  currentIndex = tempIndex;
 }
  
  $("#beforeCells").html("Before Swap: Should Have 6 Cell Count Each");
  $("#afterCells").html("After Swap: Should Have 6 Cell Count Each");
  
 if (newIndex !== -1 && currentIndex !== -1 && currentIndex !== newIndex) {
  // Iterate through each row, swapping the elements
  var rows = $("#myTable > tbody > tr");
    var numRows = rows.length;
  var tbody = document.getElementById("myBody");
    
    // Calculate if the index is in the middle of the column groups
  var tr, sourceElement, targetElement;
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {
   tr = rows[rowIndex];
      
      sourceElement = tr.cells[currentIndex]; // 3
   targetElement = tr.cells[newIndex];  // 5 (because we swapped)
      
      // Only print header and first row (after all are the same as first row)
      if (rowIndex === 0 || rowIndex === 1) {
       $("#beforeCells").html($("#beforeCells").html() + "<br>" + tr.cells.length);
      }
      
   if (typeof sourceElement !== "undefined" && typeof targetElement !== "undefined") {   
    // Keep a reference to swap in the target element
    var sourceSibling = sourceElement.nextSibling;
    if (targetElement.nextSibling) {
     tr.insertBefore(sourceElement, targetElement);
    } else {
     tr.appendChild(sourceElement);
    }
    
    if (sourceSibling) {
     // Place column before target, shift columns left
     tr.insertBefore(targetElement, sourceSibling);
    } else {
     tr.appendChild(targetElement);
    }
   }
      
      // Only print header and first row (after all are the same as first row)
      if (rowIndex === 0 || rowIndex === 1) {
       $("#afterCells").html($("#afterCells").html() + "<br>" + tr.cells.length);
      }
  }
 }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style= "position: relative; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 30px;">
<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
<table id="myTable" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody id="myBody">
<tr id="headerRow" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"><th>Column 0</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>Column 5</th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

<button onClick="swapColumns(3, 4)">
Click Me (Cells are broken)!
</button>

<button onClick="clickFunction(3, 4)">
Click Me For Workaround (Refresh First)!
</button>

<div id="beforeCells">
Before Swap: Should Have 6 Cell Count Each
</div>
<div id="afterCells">
After Swap: Should Have 6 Cell Count Each
</div>
```

Note: I am not using JQuery in my own code, it was just used in the Fiddle to speed up accessing and embedding text for my example.

I also included a workaround that I found, which would allow me to perform the SAME swap without making the cells list go out of sync. The key was that each of my swap operations involved the last cell element in the row. See this in play in the example.

Cheers!

Comment: Tables are very fickle. Setting a row to `position:absolute` is almost bound to cause some weirdness...